# Sorting variables based on which are bigger than others

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph

Given multiple abstract objects, but not their value, and a list of which objects are bigger than other objects, find the biggest object.

---

One thought I had was representing the objects in a directed graph.An outgoing connection will indicated that the node which the connection originated from is bigger than the node which receives the connection.
Therefore nodes with only outgoing connections will have no known node bigger than itself meaning it's the biggest of them all. If there are multiple nodes with only outgoing connections, then there's not enough given information to definitively pick the biggest node.

[image]
For example given this graph we known that nodes 4 and 5 are currently the biggest but it would require a connection to tell who's the biggest between these two.

[image]
On the other hand in this graph node 4 is the sole node with only outgoing connections and therefore is the biggest.

This method has worked on the examples I've tried, but I'd like to know if this method is even correct or if somebody can think of an example that will prove the method to be false or if somebody can prove this method is correct or if somebody has a proven working approach to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any object that isn't on the "smaller" side of any relation might be the biggest.

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes, that is what is meant by a node with only outgoing connections. So yes, any objects (nodes) that isn't on the smaller side of any relation (only has outgoing connections) might be the biggest, but when there's only of of these objects, does that imply that its the biggest? I think so, but I'm not sure and I'd like to see if somebody can prove this or prove it to be false.

Comment: If it's given that there *is* a biggest object, then yes, if there's a single object that isn't known to be smaller than another one, then it must be the biggest.  That's self-evident. I can't imagine how you'd prove it to someone who can't accept it as stated.